# Can I use the Module Compress::Raw::Zlib

Tags: perl

Team,

I have no Install permissions on my AIX Server. I have to use the Module Compress::Raw::Zlib as part of dependency of Excel::Writer::XLSX .

I have included the module in my program like

```
BEGIN {
 push @INC,"/home/user/xx/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.75/lib";
 push @INC,"/home/user/xx/Archive-Zip-1.34/lib";
 push @INC,"/home/user/xx/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.063/lib";
}
```

While running the program I am getting the below error 
Can't locate loadable object for module Compress::Raw::Zlib in @INC

Can you please help me in this. Do I need to install this modules ? is there any other way to chive the functionality for creating .xlsx files using perl.

Regards
David

Comment: You can try to install them locally and then use: ``use lib './library_location'`` to make it possible to include those libraries

Comment: I am getting Out of Memory error with cpan or cpanm. So there is no such option to install in my local directory. I have no credentials to enter as root

Answer (score 0):

`push @INC,"/home/user/xx/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.75/lib";
push @INC,"/home/user/xx/Archive-Zip-1.34/lib";
push @INC,"/home/user/xx/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.063/lib";`

will work only for non-XS modules. For XS modules you need the blib/arch:

`push @INC,"/home/user/xx/Archive-Zip-1.34/blib/arch";
push @INC,"/home/user/xx/Archive-Zip-1.34/blib/lib";
push @INC,"/home/user/xx/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.063/blib/arch";
push @INC,"/home/user/xx/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.063/blib/lib";`

But better install them via local::lib. Install local::lib manually, not via cpan, and then continue via cpan.